# Cómo puedo programar esto?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql, trigger

soy nuevo en esto. Quizá alguien me pueda ayudar con lo siguiente: Estoy realizando una aplicación con conexión a base de datos de postgresql, y estaría necesitando que desde la misma base de datos se realize automáticamente una acción, ya sea un INSERT, UPDATE o DELETE en una de las tablas, al cumplirse una fecha determinada.
Lo que llevo viendo hasta ahora es que los llamados triggers o disparadores de una función son posibles de realizar únicamente cuando se hace un INSERT, un UPDATE, o un DELETE en cualquiera de las tablas con las que se esté trabajando, pero nada dice de poder hacerlo por ejemplo haciendo una comparación de la fecha actual (current_date) con la que se ha ingresado a una de las celda de alguna tabla, lo que estaría siendo funcional para el vencimiento de un plazo, por ejempo.
Me interesa saber si estas acciones son posibles en postgresql, ya que me gustaría que se sigan realizando cambios en las tablas de las bases de datos automáticamente sin que yo esté usando el programa o lo tenga apagado.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un trigger no está pensado para esto que vos necesitas. Por lo que tengo entendido postgresql no tiene una herramienta de planificaciones incorporadas por lo que tenes que ir por alguna opcion extra. Este tipo de funcionalidades no son propias de sql si no mas bien de los motores que utilices.

En estos casos lo que vos necesitas es un deamon que corra en segundo plano y que si se cumple una condición (que sea una determinada fecha) que ejecute una acción que vos especificas (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE).

Buscando rápidamente di con esta pagina que presenta algunas opciones [Job Scheduling Tools for PostgreSQL](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/overview-job-scheduling-tools-postgresql)

Podrías refinar tu pregunta o buscar mas acerca de `Herramientas de planificacion de trabajos/tareas con postgrest`. Espero que esto oriente tu busqueda.

Comment: Andrés, gracias por responderme. Lo que estoy buscando es que mi base de datos realice actualizaciones cada cierto tiempo, es decir, que cumplida una fecha determinada se realizen cambios en las tablas de datos, sin yo tener que estar escribiendo código en el pgadmin.
Al parecer entendiste lo que quiero hacer, y  esa es una posible solución, aunque no me termina de convencer del todo (si es que no he leído mal) pensando en el caso de que el usuario de mi aplicación tenga que cambiar el ordenador, y al hacerlo tenga que volver a programarse el cron job en el nuevo sistema operativo.

Comment: No la descarto, pero he encontrado otra solución, que es crear un job desde pgadmin directamente, que era algo que no sabía hasta este momento.